# My page does not display in IE but does in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have the below html that is supposed to create a fly out Menu.  In Chrome and FF it works as expected.  Unfortunately in IE8 all I get is a tiny white box & in IE9 it does nothing at all.  I used the Developer Tools(F12) and monitored the Network which showed the following successful **GET** --> `/icenter/config/wwcMenuContent.html GET 304 text/html   473 B   109 ms  JS Library XMLHttpRequest   156 0   109 0   0   47`

Anyone help me out here?

### MenuControl

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>          
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fg.menu.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css" href="fg.menu.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link type="text/css" href="theme/ui.all.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- style exceptions for IE 6 -->
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fg-menu-ipod .fg-menu li { width: 95%; }
        .fg-menu-ipod .ui-widget-content { border:0; }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->    

    <script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function(){    
        // or from an external source
        $.get('wwcMenuContent.html', function(data){ // grab content from another page
            $('#hierarchy').menu({
                autoShow: true,  //SSLOAN set to auto show
                content: data,
                backLink: false,
                crumbDefaultText: ' '
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- We override there stylesheet here so the div doesn't appear to the eye -->
    <div id="hierarchy" style="border:solid 1px white; width:0px;"><img style="width:15px; height:10px; vertical-align:top; border:none;" alt=" " src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAJH/AP///wAAAMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAABAAEAQAICVAEAOw=="/></div>
</body>
```

### MenuContent

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">AODA/MH Center</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://wwcshare/icenter/SitePages/AODA%20Information.aspx">AODA Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://wwcshare/icenter/SitePages/Community%20Resources.aspx">Community Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://wwcshare/icenter/SitePages/Consultant%20Schedules.aspx">Consultant Schedules</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_norris">Chuck Norris</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darth_vader">Darth Vader</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackie_chan">Jackie Chan</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_jobs">Steve Jobs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://wwcshare/icenter/SitePages/Guidelines,%20Policies%20and%20Service%20Expectations.aspx">Guidelines, Policies, and Service Expectations</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://wwcshare/icenter/SitePages/Mental%20Health%20Information.aspx">Mental Health Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://wwcshare/icenter/SitePages/Tools%20and%20Forms.aspx">Tools and Forms</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://wwcshare/icenter/SitePages/Topics,%20Schedules%20and%20Sign-Up%20Sheets.aspx">Topis, Schedules, and Sign-Up Sheets</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Case Management Center</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Forms Center</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Functional Screen Center</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MCO Benefit Package Center</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Self-Directed Supports Center</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Social Service Specialist Center<a></li>
</ul>
```

---

Good Lord, you ain't kidding IE is picky.  my last `<a></a>` is missing the `/`.  That was causing the entire page to not display.  Thanks.

Comment: MenuContent doesn't close the UL tag ?

Comment: It was there, the formatting(SO's) was 'hiding' it for lack of better explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there the last-line missing in your post, or do you actually have the closing `</ul>` missing.  If so, that will do it.

IE is very much more fussy than the other browsers with regard to the correct validity of code coming in via AJAX methods.  Always make sure it is perfectly valid or IE will just do nothing.

Comment: Sorry, SO Formatting was hiding the `</ul>` for some reason.

Comment: Marking this as accepted answer since your statement that *"IE is very much more fussy"* is what led to the answer.  Thanks

Comment: @Refracted Paladin Well I'm not sure it constitutes a total answer.  But it is a very common solution to many questions asked.  Whenever there is a case of an AJAX call not working in IE, but fine elsewhere, it is usually down to a validation issue.  More often than not duplicate IDs or unclosed-blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be due to the lack of a `<!DOCTYPE` declaration. This makes IE run in Quirks Mode, causing unexpected behaviour and lack of functionality. Try adding the correct `<!DOCTYPE` to the HTML file and see if this makes any difference.

Comment: You mean this --> `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
`  That is there, it was just giving me formating trouble in my question so I removed it.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Fair enough. Disregard my answer then :p Orbling seems to have found the problem.